# How to acces all pixels under a QPainterPath

Tags: c++, qt, image-processing, drawing

can someone say me how to access all the pixels, that are under a `QPainterPath`?

The Elements of `QPainterPath` have some methods like `isLineTo()`, so my first idea was to create a linear function with the start and end point. But that's a problem, if the path includes a vertical line.

Greetings

**//UPDATE**

Maybe this is a better question: 
How to draw a linear path on a image and gather all the points from it?

Comment: Maybe `QPainterPath::elementAt(int)` could help?

Comment: this method don't return every pixel of a path. The path only contains waypoints (elements). Each element has methods like `isLineTo()`, `isCurveTo()` and `isMoveTo()`

Comment: I've got feeling that you asking wrong question. First describe what is your problem/what are you trying to do. Do not ask us how to fix your solution of some mysterious problem (I'm pretty sure your solution is wrong or to complicated for the task which you didn't want to describe).

Comment: yes, maybe this is a wrong question. I've updated it

Comment: @501-notimplemented, if you have a solid background and draw a line on it (black pen), you can scan the resulting image and extract all pixels that have black color - just an idea.

Comment: @vahancho: thanks for this idea. Now i found another solution, that has more performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a performant solution to get all points from a line:

```cpp
            QLineF line(lastPoint,currentPoint);
            for (int var = 0; var < line.length(); ++var) {
                x=line.x1()+var*cos(line.angle());
                y=line.y1()+var*sin(line.angle());
                //qDebug()<<x<<"  "<<y;
```

with this, i also get the points from a vertical line.

Greetings